# Can I use a custom ThreadFactory in a Java based ActiveMQ client?

Tags: java, multithreading, activemq-classic, threadpool

I'm using ActiveMQ and I have a very simple client implementing the MessageListener interface. This works well in so far as it is triggered for each new message added to the queue. However, when I try to process the message I get an error that comes from the fact that I am running this client within another application that has a number of requirements on the threads that are being used within it. When using the ExecutorService I have the option of plugging in a custom ThreadFactory which allows me to create threads that meet the system requirements.

Can the same approach - using a custom ThreadFactory - be used for an ActiveMQ client? I know that I can set a number of parameters to limit the amount of threads and so on but I can I also plug in my custom ThreadFactory?

Comment: Is your problem with ActiveMQ, which seems unlikely, or with some other (application server?) framework?

Comment: No, ActiveMQ works as expected, the issue occurs when I try to use a class (called a service) from my own application.  The client is created from this service which is also passed to the client upon creation so that it has a reference to it. When I try to call upon methods in this service I get the error because the thread running the MessageListener (the client) is not a correct thread (from the viewpoint of the service class).

Comment: So, your question really has to do with your underlying service.

Comment: No, the question is: Can I get ActiveMQ to accept a custom ThreadFactory to use when creating the thread that runs the MessageListener.